# ValueError: too many values but need all the variables

Tags: python

I was running a code and got a problem with those statements

```
with open(distance_f, 'r') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            x1, x2, d = line.strip().split(' ')
```

the error is

```
x1, x2, d = line.strip().split(' ')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

the file contains data like

```
 1   2  28.50
 1   3  14.62
 1   4  34.71
```

there is a tab character between each number
I tried to replace tab character with space but got this error

```
x1, x2, d = line.strip().split(' ')

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

I read a solution for the second error is to delete one of the variables.. but I want to use the three variable

Comment: You are trying to split by single space but the columns are separated by 2 or more spaces

Comment: so the value should separate with a single space?

Comment: just use `line.strip().split()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try providing no arguments to split, which will by default consume all the intermediate whitespace as a delimiter.
See difference in example below

```py
>>> 'a     b    c'.split()
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> 'a     b    c'.split(' ')
['a', '', '', '', '', 'b', '', '', '', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there is a tab character between each number why don't split on tab character ("\t")?

```
line.strip().split("\t")
```